# Why am I off by 1-2 when trying to multiply with bit manipulation?

Tags: python, python-3.x, bit-manipulation

I'm trying to multiply two numbers without arithmetic operators. I'm aware there might be more efficient ways, but I'm just trying to work from the ground up (start off with something inefficient, create something efficient myself afterwards).

The way I've set this up is so that, to determine x * y, I add y to itself x times. I created an 'add' function that adds two numbers using just shifting, masking and carrys. Here it is:

```
def add(x, y):
    carry, result, tracker = 0,0,0
    while x or y:
        i,j = x&1,y&1

        if (i^j == 0 and i&j == 1 and carry == 1) or (i^j == 1 and i&j == 0 and carry == 0):
             result |= (1<<tracker)

        elif (i^j == 0 and i&j == 1 and carry == 0) or (i^j == 1 and i&j == 0 and carry == 1):
             result |= (0<<tracker)
             carry = 1
    
        tracker +=1
        x>>=1
        y>>=1

    if carry == 1:
        result |= 1<<tracker

    return result
```

The way the add function works is that, when adding two digits - if the result is 3 or 1, I add 1 to the result and do not change the carry (so if its 3, we'll need a carry to represent 11 in Base 2). If the result is 2 - we'll add 0 to the result, and create a carry of 1.

And here is my multiply function:

```
def multiply(x, y):
   result = 0
   while y>0:
        result = add(result,x)
        y-=1
   return result
```

The add function works perfectly, yet when I'm multiplying, I'm always off by 1-2 in terms of the final result.

Comment: Can you give an example of input `x` and `y` that produce the wrong result? Did you try tracing through the code to see what the value of `result` is each time through the loop in `multiply`?

Comment: In `add`, what should happen when `i == 1 and j == 1 and carry == 1`? Does your code explicitly handle that case? (Hint: in that case, what is `i&j`? What is `i^j`?) What *will* happen in your code? Do you see a problem here?

Comment: Hint: Your logic for the full adder step should treat `i`, `j` and `carry` symmetrically, since each value has the same effect on the calculation.

Comment: @PranavHosangadi So sorry about that - I should've seen that myself. Copy and pasting made things weird, but it's fixed now.

Comment: Strictly speaking, your `add` *doesn't* just rely on shifting, masking, and carries. It also relies on, well, addition, as you need to add 1 to tracker. (You can initialize `tracker` to 1 and simply shift *it* by one position as necessary, to fix that dependency. Note that `0 << tracker` is always just 0 anyway.)

Comment: @KarlKnechtel an example would be 5*3. Tracking it revealed that it's correct on the first loop (5), but the next two loops are 12, 17, with 17 being the final result.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel The poster handled that case in the very first `i^j == 0 and i&j == 1 and carry == 1` condition part correctly. But they forgot `i ==0 and j == 0 and carry == 1`

Comment: Ah, yes. I need more sleep - I was seeing `^` and thinking `|`.

Comment: @MichaelButscher You nailed it. I missed out on two cases - one that you mentioned, the other being i ==0 and j == 0 and carry == 0. So sorry for the dumb mistake. My function gives the correct result now.

Comment: @chepner You're completely right. I totally missed that. Thanks so much for the tip.

Comment: Post your analysis and the corrected function as an answer.